# Java write test for inputStream with javax.ws.rs.client

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, jax-rs, inputstream

I'm having a GET api using java.ws.rs like this:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getMyFile() throws AbsoluteException {
    StreamingOutput outputStream;
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    try {
        final InputStream responseStream = client.target(myFileUrl).request().get(InputStream.class);
        outputStream = new StreamingOutput() {
            @Override
            public void write(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
                int length;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[downloadBufferSize];
                while ((length = responseStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                out.flush();
                responseStream.close();
            }
        };
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
    return Response
            .ok(outputStream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename = " + myFile)
            .build();
}
```

I don't know how to write unitTest for it, using Mockito or any others. 
My Test method as below but it doesn't work:

```
@Test
public void getMyFile_Success() throws IOException {
    final Client mockClient = Mockito.mock(Client.class);
    final File initialFile = new File("src/test/resources/TestFile.txt");
    final InputStream targetStream =
            new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(initialFile));
    Mockito.when(mockClient.target("myUrl")
            .request().get(InputStream.class))
            .thenReturn(targetStream);
    Invocation.Builder request = target(CONTEXT_ROOT).request();
    Response response = request.get(Response.class);
    assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode());
}
```

Comment: The first thing I would do is create a service to handle the API call. Separation of concerns. Then you can mock service and inject it. Other than that, if you want to use Mockitio to mock the client, you have to understand that each chained call returns something else, so you have to go through the who when(..).then(..) for each of the chained calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I success with powermock that able to mock the constructor as well as static method.
Below is my code:

```
    Client mockClient = Mockito.mock(Client.class); 
    @Before
    public void initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClientBuilder.class);
        PowerMockito.when(ClientBuilder.newClient()).thenReturn(this.mockClient);
    }   

    public void getMyFile_Success() throws Exception {
        Invocation.Builder myBuilder = Mockito.mock(Invocation.Builder.class);
        WebTarget webTarget = Mockito.mock(WebTarget.class);
        Mockito.when(mockClient.target(myUrl)).thenReturn(webTarget);
        Mockito.when(webTarget.request()).thenReturn(myBuilder);
        final File initialFile = new File("src/test/resources/TestFile.txt");
        InputStream targetStream =
                new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(initialFile));
        Mockito.when(myBuilder
                .get(InputStream.class))
                .thenReturn(targetStream);
        Invocation.Builder request = target(CONTEXT_ROOT).request();
        Response response = request.get(Response.class);
        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode());
    }
```